# Paypal IPN returns verified on sandbox, but invalid on live

Tags: paypal, sandbox, paypal-ipn

So I have been using paypal, and sandbox mode everything works fine. Yet when I move over to live paypal with real money, IPN returns INVALID.

I am using a version of the script here ( https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt ) modified to my needs, only bits that are different are the db interactions etc

I have found this issue here ( http://www.hebtech.co.uk/blog/paypal-ipn-invalid-on-live-server-but-valid-on-test-server-fixed/ ) which seems to be the problem I am having, and basically says its to do with a carriage return in the optional second line of the address (which on test accounts in sandbox, isnt filled out). But the solution in the main post and another in the comments dont work, as below

```
$value = preg_replace('/(.*[^%^0^D])(%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);
```

OR

```
$value = preg_replace('/(.*?)(%0D%0A|%0A)(.*)/i','${1}%0D%0A${3}',$value);
```

Any ideas? Driving me mad. Its not stopping the payment, but it just means on the site, changing the status to paid has to be done manually

Comment: check your charset and ssl connection.
If you can post your script is better :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
$value = preg_replace('/%0D%0A|%0A/i','%0D%0A',$value);
```

I have also problem with character `;` in custom field. Look in all fields you send to PayPall. Also check in all field any character which is not A-Z or 0-9.

Last thing you can try is set charset in your language encoding options: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-language-encoding